# Unlock My app with Face recognition using BiometricPrompt in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, face-recognition, face-detection

I am using a `BiometricPrompt` for unlock my app with face id on login screen fragment. But its show only finger print sensor in android version 10,11,12.but in android 1version 13` its show a finger print sensor or face recognition. but i want implement in all devices latest versions in android.

**I’m using this dependency in gradle file:-**

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'

private lateinit var executor: Executor
private lateinit var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt
private lateinit var promptInfo: BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo

//oncreate ()
showBiometricPrompt()

promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
.setTitle("Face Lock")
.setDescription("Position your face within the frame.")
.setConfirmationRequired(false)
//.setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
.setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK or     BiometricManager.Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
 .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
.build()

 biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor, object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

 override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
            // Authentication succeeded, implement your logic here
            // For face lock, you can consider this as a successful authentication
   showSuccessDialog()
 }

 override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
            // Authentication failed, handle it if needed
            showErrorDialog()
  }

 override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
            // Authentication error, handle it if needed
            showErrorDialog()
        }
    })
}


private fun showSuccessDialog() {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Success")
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Face lock authentication successful!")
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
        // Optionally, you can close the activity here or perform other actions.
    }

    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
}


private fun showErrorDialog() {
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error")
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Face lock authentication failed. Please try again.")
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
        // Optionally, you can trigger another attempt at biometric authentication here.
    }

    val alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
}

private fun showBiometricPrompt() {
    biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

Please suggest me how to implement a face recognition in my app code on login fragment?

Comment: Do those older Android versions even support face unlock at all? It may also be device dependent.

Comment: @Jorn, If Android versions support face unlock and the device is unlocked with a face, such as Android versions 11, 12, and 13, the app should show face recognition with this code. However, it only shows the fingerprint sensor in Android versions 11 and 12. In Android version 13 devices, it shows both the fingerprint sensor and face recognition sensor.